# Why are the properties of Google_Service_Drive files only returning null?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

I want to list all files in a folder shared with my Service Account. I'm trying to figure out what files have a 'parent' attribute set to the folder ID or folder name. However, all the objects that I output show "NULL" for nearly all fields. I've searched through the Google Drive API v3 and I can't even find the listFiles() function in it. Additionally, the documentation recommends using the Files.list function for outputting a list of files but when I use the Files.list function, I get an error as if the method doesn't exist. So I went back to using listFiles()... My code looks like this:

```
public function getTitlesAndIDs($folderID)
{

    // $capabilities = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities();
    // $capabilities->canListChildren = true;
    $files = $this->driveService->files->listFiles();

    var_dump($files);
}
```

Trying to add capabilities just returns NULL as well. When I run listFiles() I get output like this:

```
["files"]=>
  array(100) {
    [0]=>
    object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#77 (65) {
      ["collection_key":protected]=>
      string(6) "spaces"
      ["appProperties"]=>
      NULL
      ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
      string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
      ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
      string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
      ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["createdTime"]=>
      NULL
      ["description"]=>
      NULL
      ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
      NULL
      ["fileExtension"]=>
      NULL
      ["folderColorRgb"]=>
...
```

Why are the values all coming back as NULL and how do I fix this so I can search by parent folders? Is there a php equivalent to the Files.list function?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its probably null because your service account doesn't have any files yet.   Just sharing a directory does not by default give it access to the files within said directory.   Also there is no list all you need to do a file.list then paginate over any additional pages of data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The directory does have files in it. I also went through by hand and shared each document with the service account. Php doesn't use "." notation. It uses files->list... but there is no function in the api under the "files" parameter called "list". There is only listFiles() which doesn't do what I need it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make sure that there are files that the service account has access to.   Once you have done so this should be able to list the files.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $file->getName(), $file->getId());
  }
}
```

Code ripped from [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php)

Comment: This helped me find the answer. For anyone else who might find this question... Apparently in PHP the Files.list function "is" the listFiles() function although the latter name does not appear on the page of the former.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what @DalmTo said, one important thing to explicitly point out: you received `NULL` for nearly all fields because you didn't supply a list of fields, `'fields'` as optional parameter.

Comment: This is the valid answer for me! I forgot this param in the query, the example code only requests the id and the name. If you don´t enter any other field (like "trashed" in my case) its value will always be null. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Google Drive API V3 properties such as `id, name, kind` and `description`, there are custom file attributes available to the developer via `properties` and `appProperties`.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/properties

Google Drive `properties` key / value pairs are controlled and manipulated by your application.

Throughout Google Drive V3 documentation, the term "properties" also refers to *metadata*. I found this very confusing. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

In Google Drive V2, there are copious examples of how to manipulate key / value `properties` using PHP, but in Google Drive V3 the `properties` API was significantly changed, and PHP code examples are very sparse.

By modifying the example code above, I was able to retrieve my customized properties.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Print the names, IDs and properties for up to 10 files.
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10,
  'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name, properties)'
);
$results = $service->files->listFiles($optParams);

if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
  print "No files found.\n";
} else {
  print "Files:\n";
  foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", "name: ".$file->getName(), "ID: ".$file->getId());
      foreach ($file->getProperties() as $key => $value) {
        printf("%s%s\n","-key: ".$key,", value: ".$value);
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to share my extension of the original answer for those developers who land on this page looking for a PHP example of manipulating `properties` and `appProperties` in Google Drive V3.